# NSImageView being clipped off

Tags: swift, appkit, nsimage

I'm trying to display an NSImageView with a symbol icon inside it, however the top and right sides are being clipped off. I tried changing the `imageScaling`, `imageAlignment`, `bounds`, and `image.size`, but it says the same.

Here's what I'm doing right now:

```swift
let iconImage = NSImage(named: .myImage)!
let icon = NSImageView(image: topBarButtonIcon)
icon.frame = CGRect(x: 7.5, y: 7.5, width: 15, height: 15)
icon.animates = true
icon.isEditable = false
icon.imageAlignment = .alignCenter
icon.imageScaling = .scaleAxesIndependently
```

Here's how it shows up:

[image: How it shows up]

This might matter: I'm sub-viewing the icon into a custom NSButton class I made, it's given a 30x30 frame, but even if I change it to something like 100x100 the icon says clipped.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you check or share the image file that you are trying to display? Is it possible that itself got an issue?

Comment: Is the dark green background part of the image?

Comment: @BurakAkkaş No, the image works normally if I use it in SwiftUI (I copy/pasted it from the SwiftUI app's asset catalog to this app's).

Comment: @Willeke No, that's the background of the NSButton I was sub-viewing it in.

Comment: Post a [mre] please.